# Google Cloud Run (fully managed): Custom domain mapping not possible

Tags: google-cloud-run

When I try to map a custom domain to my service I get: "Failed to create a domain mapping: Creating domain mappings is not allowed in europe-west3". Google Run seems to be pretty useless for many use cases if it can't be mapped to custom domains, so I wonder if it is really not possible or this is an error or I have to enable something before this feature can be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the official documentation :

[Mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains)

> You can use a custom domain rather than the default address that Cloud
> Run provides for a deployed service.
>
> To use a custom domain for a service, you map your service to the
> custom domain, then update your DNS records. You can map a service to
> a domain, such as example.comor to a subdomain, such as
> subdomain.example.com.

**It is not possible to map custom domains to Cloud Run (fully managed) services in**

```
asia-east2
asia-northeast2
asia-northeast3
asia-southeast1
asia-southeast2
asia-south1
australia-southeast1
europe-west2
**europe-west3**
europe-west6
northamerica-northeast1
southamerica-east1
```

Comment: What a pity! Thanks, this information is missing in the German version of the docs by now.

Comment: Ok it's not possible, but why? and what are we uspposed to do if we're not in one of those zones?

Comment: any info when it become available on those zones?